# Getting value of database field in Crystal Reports

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

Currently I'm working on legacy application, that uses crystal report engine. I have to get value of database fields programmatically. As I've assumed, I need proper event for getting next code to work:

```
Report.Database.Tables(1).Fields(1).Value
```

But the `value` is always empty in `DownloadStarted/Finished` event handlers. What I'm doing wrong and is it at least possible?

Comment: you are right friend i try it too and it returns null.can you tell me what is in your mind?? maybe i can help you about that

Comment: Really don't know at this moment. I'll try something with query, fortunately it is possible to get it. But I wonder why there is `value` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you want to get value of your table fields in program the best way is that you get the field name from report and then connect to your table directly and use report field names as the table columns name
i do it in c# i hope it can help you in vb6 too:

```
string name = report2.Database.Tables[1].Fields[1].Name;
string[]  names = name.Split('.');
```

and then add your database to your program and use names like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string[] value = dt.Columns[names[1]];
```

Comment: Alas it couldn't be done in this way. I will look through `DataTable` class in VB6, but seems to me, that it will behave different.

Answer (score 1):

if you just need your tables values, you can use my last answer, but if you need value of database fields in crystal report, i mean something like formula field ,this code can help you:

```
CRAXDRT.FormulaFieldDefinitions definitions = report2.FormulaFields;
string formulaText = "IF " + report2.Database.Tables[1].Fields[3].Name 
    + " > 10 THEN" + report2.Database.Tables[1].Fields[2].Name;
definitions.Add("Test", formulaText);
report2.Sections[1].AddFieldObject(definitions[1], 0, 0);
```

Comment: I've got more than fifty reports, each report consist from more than 20 fields from database, which differs. There also could be `UNION`s. Manual adding of formulas is a little bit awkward and that isn't correct solution.